# how to shift a dropdown menu upwards

Tags: html, css

I can't shift my dropdown menu upwards... to align it better with the text. I tried margin-top:-10px but it does not seem to have any effect.

```html
<h1 style="display: inline;"> Most popular     </h1>
<select class="selectpicker" style="margin-bottom: 20px; margin-top: -20px">
  <option id="7">last week</option>
  <option id="30">last month</option>
  <option id="180">last 6 months</option>
  <option id="365">last year</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Try setting the `vertical-align` property on the `<h1>` and/or the `<select>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default select-box can have different views (width, height ...) on different browsers, so when you push it up with fixed amount (for example in 5px), this may have different results on different browsers.

So would be better first of all style your select-box to have cross browser view (anyway you can avoid this step, my solutions will work without this too) for example like this:

```
select {    
    width: 200px;
    height: 34px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #555;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

**Example 1** provides how to align h1 & select vertically with each other:

```
.example1 h1,
.example1 select {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 35px; /* set any value as you need */
}

<div class="example1">
   <h1>Most popular</h1>
   <select class="selectpicker">
      <option id="7">last week</option>
      <option id="30">last month</option>
      <option id="180">last 6 months</option>
      <option id="365">last year</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

**Example 2** provides how you can positioning select box relative to h1 element as you want, just set top position:

```
.example2 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 200px; /* set value equal to select-box width */
}

.example2 select {
  top: 3px; /* set any value to position select-box */
  right: 0;  
  display: block;
  position: absolute;    
}

<div class="example2">
    <h1>Most popular</h1>
    <select class="selectpicker">
        <option id="7">last week</option>
        <option id="30">last month</option>
        <option id="180">last 6 months</option>
        <option id="365">last year</option>
     </select>
 </div>
```

See working examples [here](https://jsfiddle.net/aani/7v2yhjth/8/)

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try taking out the margins and setting the `vertical-align` to `top`:

```
<h1 style="display: inline;"> Most popular     </h1>
<select class="selectpicker" style="vertical-align:top ">
  <option id="7">last week</option>
  <option id="30">last month</option>
  <option id="180">last 6 months</option>
  <option id="365">last year</option>
</select>
```

Also depends on your parent container.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rough answer.  I have added this code to your `select`: `position:relative; top:-5px;`

```html
<h1 style="display: inline;"> Most popular     </h1>
<select class="selectpicker" style="position:relative; top:-5px; margin-bottom: 20px; margin-top: -20px">
  <option id="7">last week</option>
  <option id="30">last month</option>
  <option id="180">last 6 months</option>
  <option id="365">last year</option>
</select>
```